# How to prevent boilerplate Java code on parsing a complex XML file?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, boilerplate

I have written a XML parser with DocumentBuilderFactory for a complex XML file. Because there are many different node types that there are many boilerplate code. For every node type (NodeName) I have a loop over the children and a switch for the possible children elements.

Is it possible only to register the needed code for the different node types and then run the parsing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several ways:

- [Refactor](http://stuffnwotnot.blogspot.com/2009/05/simple-way-to-parse-xml-in-java-2.html) repeated code into reuseable methods.
- Make use of [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp) to select specific nodes directly.
- Convert XML to fullworthy Javabean with a tool, e.g. [XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

The Java DOM parsing API is indeed a bit boilerplate. There are some other libraries:

- [dom4j](http://www.dom4j.org/)
- [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/)
- [Crimson](http://xml.apache.org/crimson/)
- [Apache XML libraries](http://projects.apache.org/indexes/category.html#xml)

Answer (score 0):

Writing a custom parser may not be the way to go.
If you merely needs to map XML into Java objects, a preexisting library or tool is best. Let someone else worry about boilerplate.

I'm a big fan of Apache Digester, which takes a bunch of rules and buuilds the Java beans for you. For a little more of a learning curve but more flexibility and power you could use Apache XMLBeans.